# Ant Build not picking up relative path correctly in Jenkins Pipeline Job

Tags: jenkins, ant, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Ant as my build tool and i have a property defined in my build.xml file like the following and this property is been called in many targets.

**Not Working:**

```
  <property name="lib" value="../lib"/>
```

In Jenkins Pipeline Job, the above property doesn't but when I set the absolute path for the above property then works fine. I have not experienced this issue in normal freestyle jobs.

**Working Fine:**

```
  <property name="lib" value="/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Test_Build_REL-1/lib"/>
```

Because of setting the absolute path to the property, everytime I will have to modify my build.xml file with the new path if my Job name changes.

Note: My Job name gets changed as per the releases.

Do we have any workaround for this issue?

Comment: In all likelihood, it's simply because your lib directory isn't located one level higher than your workspace's base directory. The absolute path you posted kind of suggests that. For starters, try using the `location` attribute instead of `value` when you set that property. Then I'd suggest echo'ing its value to the console right afterwards to verify.

Comment: What CAustin says. I think value="lib" should also work